# Form Validation JavaScript number always return false

Tags: javascript, html, forms

my textbox ALWAYS returns with field is not a number, even if it is.

HTML

```
<form name = garysForm>
Number of adults: <input type="number" size="6" id="ofAdults" name="adultBox" min="0" max="50" required><br>
Number of children: <input type="number" size="6" id="ofChild" min="0" max="50" required><br>
Date:<input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" required><br>   
<Button type="button"   onclick="BookingFare(); return false;">Calculate</button><br>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var field = document.forms["garysForm"]["adultBox"].value;

    if (isNaN(field.value)) {
            alert('Please enter a valid number');

        }
```

Comment: You're not selecting anything, the name is invalid as it's not quoted, and using `document.forms` is a really poor way to get an element that has an ID

Comment: Also, you're calling `value` ***TWICE***, which is the real problem

Comment: It should be just `if (isNaN(field)) {`

Comment: tried that it doesn't help

Comment: and i honestly don't care if calling document.forms is a really poor way, that is not causing a problem.... Maybe you shouldn't be so condescending if you don't even give the correct solution ?

Comment: I'm not condescending, just noting that `document.getElementById('ofAdults')` would be a much better approach

Comment: And here it is working ->  **http://jsfiddle.net/beehqb4o/**

Comment: The number input returns an empty string when only invalid characters are entered, and isNaN on an empty string doesn't work

Comment: Thank you much better my dear old boy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the .elements method.

```
var field = document.forms["garysForm"].elements["adultBox"].value;
```

Then, you need to consider that an SPACE is also considered a number [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). So I applied the following logic.

```
var field = document.forms["garysForm"].elements["adultBox"].value;
console.log(field)
if (field=='') {
    alert('Please enter a valid number');
}
else if (isNaN(field)) {
   alert('Please enter a valid number');
}
else {
   alert(field)
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonyrod4/gqwafe7c/5/)

*Jquery is only used for demo purpose.

I hope you find this answer helpful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling field.value when you've assigned value to field.

```
var field = document.forms["garysForm"]["adultBox"].value;

if (isNaN(field.value)) {
```

Try this instead:

```
var field = document.forms["garysForm"]["adultBox"];

if (isNaN(field.value)) {
```

Comment: tried that it just breaks it so that it doesn't even relay a message back

Comment: Point me at a plunker

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the adult box using its id:

```
var field = document.getElementById("ofAdults").value;

if (isNaN(field)) {
    ....
```